# What do you mean Gear box in Serdes serializer?

Tags: pll

I read a statement from a document on Serializer. It mentions no gearbox Serializer.  Do you know what it meant?

Comment: Can you review [this existing answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/387084/9612) and [this other one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/387075/9612) and let us know what specific doubts/questions remain after reading them? (Please do so by [edit]ing your post, rather than replying in a comment)

Comment: Can you please edit your question? It should include a link to the document. If it is not possible to add a link, then maybe an image showing more of the text before and after.